# Multidimensional lists in SwiftUI that pass data

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this model:

```
struct Training: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let workout: [Workout]?
}
```

and:

```
struct Workout: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let exercices: [Exercice]?
}
```

and:

```
struct Exercice: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}
```

The data for the models is coming from an environment object.

The app will launch with an empty list of trainings and you can add trainings within the UI. Each training has a navigtaionlink to a view to add workouts to each training and in the next step you can add exercices to each workout.

In my logic I create multidimensional arrays with the structs shown above.

The trainings view is easy:

```
struct TrainingsView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

    @State var showingDetail = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                List {
                    ForEach (appState.trainings) { training in
                        NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutsView(training: training).environmentObject(self.appState)) {
                            Text(training.name)
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete(perform: appState.removeTraining)
                }
                // Button to add trainings....
                .navigationBarTitle(Text("Trainings").foregroundColor(Color.white))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `WorkoutsView` is looking the same but I have an issue with listing the items of the parent training:

```
struct WorkoutsView: View {
    // ...
    var training: Training

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List {
                ForEach (appState.trainings(training).workouts) { workout in // I know the appState call is incorrect, but I don't know how to access is correctly.
                    NavigationLink(destination: ExercicesView(workout)) {
                        Text(workout.name)
                    }
                }
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I already tried:

```
List {
    ForEach (0 ..< appState.trainings.count) {
        NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutsView(training: $0).environmentObject(self.appState)) {
            Text(appState.trainings[$0].name)
        }
    }
}
```

I could use `appState.trainings[training].workouts` in the `WorkoutsView` but I'm getting the error `Contextual closure type '() -> Text' expects 0 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body` on the NavigationLink line and don't know what to do.

Additional question: If this is close to the solution, I don't need the struct to conform to Identifiable?

Comment: You are already passing in `training`, which has `workouts` property. Can you not just do `ForEach(training.workouts)`? Why do you need the appState again?

Comment: When I add a workout I want to add it to the parent training like `appState.trainings[key???].workouts.append(workout)`

Comment: Make the passed `training: Training` variable into a binding, i.e. a `Binding<Training>`, then you can modify it directly, just like say `TextField` can modify a text property of its parent view

Comment: in the child view I define it like `@State var training: Training`. Is that, what you mean?

Comment: Yes, except it should be a `@Binding var training: Training`, and you pass a binding of a `training` from the parent. The difference between State and Binding is that State is for data that your view is the authoritative source of truth for, and binding - is when your view doesn't "own" the data, but can still modify it.

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass the training index/key (instead of training) into the child view, and access the appState directly from it

Comment: Having `@Binding` in the child and `@State` in the parent is working, but when I go back to the parent view and again to the child view, the new data is gone. I think this is because I don't add it to the appState where I load the data from. I'm now going back to my original question... How can I add the new Workout to the parent?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215032/discussion-between-t-karter-and-new-dev).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 broad approaches here, depending on how you want to design your system.

**1.** Your child views know about the app state and can modify it directly. So, the parent needs to pass the indices/keys for the child to locate which data to modify:

```
struct TrainingsView: View {
   @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

   var body: some View {
      NavigationView {
         List(0..<appState.trainings.count) { i in
            NavigationLink(destination: WorkoutsView(trainingIndex: i)) {
               Text(self.appState.trainings[i].name)
            }
         } 
      }
   }
}
```

```
struct WorkoutsView: View {
   var trainingIdx: Int
   @EnvironmentObject var appState: AppState

   var body: some View {
      VStack() {

         TextField("training name: ", text: $appState.trainings[trainingIdx].name)

         Button(action: {self.appState.trainings[trainingIdx].workouts.append(Workout(...))}) {
            Text("Add workout")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**2.** Alternatively, you might say that you don't want your child views to know about the app's state - you just want them to modify some static `struct` that they don't own (but rather owned by their parent), then you should use use a `@Binding`.

The example below is conceptual to illustrate a point:

```
struct TrainingsView: View {
   @State var trainingA = Training(...)
   @State var trainingB = Training(...)

   var body: some Body {
      NavigationView {
         List {
            WorkoutsView(training: $trainingA)
            WorkoutsView(training: $trainingB)
         }
      }
   }
}
```

```
struct WorkoutsView: View {
   @Binding var training: Training

   var body: some View {
      VStack() {

         TextField("training name: ", text: $training.name)

         Button(action: { self.training.workouts.append(Workout(...)) }) {
            Text("Add workout")
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. When I use your first approach, I am getting `ForEach<Range<Int>, Int, NavigationLink<Text, ModifiedContent<ExercisesView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Optional<AppState>>>>> count (2) != its initial count (1). `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and provide an explicit `id`!` after adding a new workout